# SonarQube - Add parameters to rule via API

Tags: sonarqube

Using SonarQube 6.0, it seems that you are unable to add parameters to rules unless they are custom. Some rules that come with plugins allow parameters, however there seems to be no way to provide these. Also, it appears that you cannot copy a rule to make it custom and add parameters that way.

One such rule:

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-javascript/blob/master/javascript-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/javascript/checks/UntrustedContentCheck.java

Any way to achieve this via the API?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to add parameter(s) to a custom rule you're implementing with the Java API ? or are you trying to enable an existing rule with parameter(s) via the Web API ? Please clarify the question, and provide examples of what you have tried so far.

Comment: No, this is not a custom rule - this is a rule that's included in the default Javascript rules. This particular rule takes a parameter - 'domainsToIgnore'. I need to add some domains so that the rule will not trigger false positives, for example whenever sourcing a file from `http://localhost` or `http://mydomain`. Currently anytime anything is sourced this rule will show a blocker, which is incorrect. I need a way to add domains to 'domainsToIgnore'.

Comment: SonarQube team - any help? I have this same situation. I want to exclude a custom type selector for the [CSS plugin](https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css-plugin/blob/4.13/css-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/css/checks/common/UnknownTypeSelectorCheck.java) but after hours of digging in docs, can't figure out how to do it. Version 6.3. Rule key is `unknown-type-selector`, key for the rule property is Exclusions, but how to set that just for this rule? And is it possible to do project-by-project?

Comment: @NicolasB.-SonarSourceTeam I have the same question about passing the Exclusions. I'm using the CSS plugin version 4.13 (https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css-plugin/issues/41). Is this something I can write in sonar-project.properties? Or is that somewhere on the Administration page of the project? Thanks!

Comment: This is how to do it https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css-plugin/issues/90